# Check if an area on jpanel has something painted on it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am currently in the process of making a simulation of evolution and am running into a problem giving all of the different bots vision. My best idea was to have a line that comes out from each side and check if that line was touching a painted square on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better to use a model (virtual concept) to make these determinations rather then relying on the physical output

Comment: Hi Cecil, and welcome to StackOverflow! Have you already completed the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)? People are more likely able (and willing) to help you if you include some more details, including a short(!) code example of what you have tried so far. You might want to check out this [helpful guide on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @fNek Great comment, and a tip *"short(!) code example"*. Note that `[mre]` in a comment auto expands to [mre].

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Better to use a model (virtual concept) to make these determinations rather then relying on the physical output"* **Plus 10**. Even from reading the title, it seemed this was an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).